# SQL Как вывести таблицу у которой два столбца берут данные из одной таблицы?

Tags: sql

Table1

| id | name | start_type | end_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Имя1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | Имя2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | Имя3 | 2 | 3 |

Table2(type)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Общий |
| 2 | Не общий |
| 3 | Другой тип |

Желаемый результат

| id | name | start_type_name | end_type_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Имя1 | Общий | Не общий |
| 2 | Имя2 | Не общий | Общий |
| 3 | Имя3 | Не общий | Другой тип |

Comment: А что вы уже изучили про JOIN'ы и что не получилось?

Comment: Через JOIN выводятся одинаковые значения как для start_type так и end_type

Comment: Напишите ваш запрос в сам вопрос, рассмотрим, поправим

Comment: Я не писал псевдонимы в JOIN'ах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select table1.id, table1.name, start_t2.name as start_type_name, end_t2.name as end_type_name from table1 
join table2 as start_t2 on table1.start_type = start_t2.id 
join table2 as end_t2 on table1.end_type = end_t2.id
```